# VMware and Homestead, The provider 'vmware_desktop' could not be found

Tags: laravel, vagrant, vmware, homestead

I can't seem to get VMWare support working with Laravel's Homestead on Windows 7.

I've bought and installed VMWare Workstation and Vagrant's VMWare plugin and added the licence for it.

I've downloaded the homestead box via the command in the laravel docs `vagrant box add laravel/homestead` and selected option 2 for vmware_desktop.

And specified `provider: vmware_desktop` in my `~/.homestead/Homestead.yml` file and run `vagrant up` from where I downloaded the Homestead Vagrant files.

And I get the message:

```
C:\Users\Ezra\Desktop\Homestead>vagrant up
The provider 'vmware_desktop' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'default'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

I've tried different provider names; like: vmware_fusion, vm_desktop, vm_fustion.. etc. Nothing works.

I've got the latest `vmware_desktop` image at v0.2.7 and visually verified the files exist in the `~/.vagrant.d/boxes` directory.

VirtualBox provider works fine. But not VMware. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Homestead working on Windows, the provider must be set to:

```
provider: vmware_workstation
```

Made a PR to the laravel docs, so this shouldn't be an issue for anyone else going forward. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5 and Homestead 2.0

Try to run

```
homestead up
```

Then

```
homestead provision
```

This will reload your `~/.homestead/Homestead.yml` for additional sites and/or configuration.

[image: homestead]

Comment: I am using vagrant/homestead on windows 7 and it works perfectly, also I can run `homestead up` from anywhere not only from where I downloaded the Homestead Vagrant files ...

Note: If you are using Windows, you may need to enable hardware virtualization (VT-x). It can usually be enabled via your BIOS.

Checkout the documentation for more details about how to configure [homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead)

Comment: You're using virtualbox!! This question is about VMWare.